# Could we do a blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I wonder if we have enough interest to start up a blog.  I would love to see a blog on here, there's a lot of stuff we could cover.  In order to start up a blog though we've gotta follow the guidelines [here](http://blogoverflow.com/getting-started/).

1. Raise the idea on the child meta. A community blog needs the
   involvement of community members. **done**
2. Define the scope and purpose of the blog. Is the blog about the site? Is it about the site’s topic? Is it about the industry around
   the topic? Keep in mind the audience of your community and their
   interests. Another generic blog about  may not be all that
   interesting.
3. Recruit contributors. Who will write entries for the blog? Starting a blog is a bit like going through the buffet line. Be
   realistic – don’t let your eyes be bigger than your stomach. Think
   seriously about if and how often you will be able to contribute a
   blog post, including research/prep time.
4. Plan a schedule. Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think about a rough idea of a schedule for the blog. Will there be one post a
   week, posted Mondays? Will there be  posts on Tuesdays and 
   posts on Fridays? You don’t need to be pushing out posts daily, but
   I would say at least one post a week.

Comment: The site is awfully young. Granted, the topic is prone to blogs (reviews), but still, there aren't many people around yet. I say wait a couple of months. Also, skim through the history of [scifi.se]'s blog: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blog?sort=newest

Answer (score 2):

I also think it's still too early to start a blog, but once the community has grown a little more this could really help promote the site further.

Especially well-written reviews about new movies might really help attract some search-engine traffic. Movie analyses and other bits about movie history could also link to interesting questions on the site itself and provide a starting point for interested readers to browse.

If we get to the point of starting a blog, I would certainly be interested in taking part.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing reviews on a facebook page at the moment that could easily be transferred here.

Answer (score 1):

**No, unfortunately we couldn't!**

As to [this announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244467/162011) the SE framework will not start any new community blogs in the near future, which puts a hold to all blog proposal efforts (for now?).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mind doing a blog about movies, reviews, services, etc, but I don't know how reliably I could update it but if it was ok for me to toss a few articles in here or there that would be a good match.